# How to select elements after find in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, algorithm, mongoose

I have interest in one problem like this: 
Initially we have document in database. for example:

```
[ {name: 1} , {name: 2}, {name: 3} , {name: 4} , {name: 5} , {name: 6} , ....]
```

I want to find some element. for example I get second element: `{name: 2}`
My problem this. after find I want to get some array element. for example `3` elements. and answer this: `[{name: 2}, {name: 3} , {name: 4}]`. I can easyly solve this problem `c++` but how can I solve this in mongoose and javascript?
Problem this:

1. Find some element to document
2. Get some numbers element to start find element.

Sorry my english. Hope you understand. Can I do this?

Comment: You can just query for the entire document using the find() method: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-find

Comment: I really didn't understand what you meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a simple query and do the rest of the operations in JS.

1. You will have to query the entire collection sorted by your 'name' field.
2. You will have to get your specific range.

```
let values = db.collection.find().sort( { name: 1 } ).exec((err, docs) =>{
//docs are your values
let docIndex = docs.findIndex((a)=>{
return a.name == 2;
});
let docsInRange = docs.slice(docIndex  ,docIndex + 3);
});
```

[findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) is finding the index for your required database document in the array.

[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) takes a slice of your array from one index to another.

This code assumes the value exists in the array and does not check for boundary errors.